# Why should we use only s3 as a data source in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Amazon S3 is the data store which is used as a data source in AWS Glue.Please thell the reason for the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have other data sources that can be connected via JDBC Protocol :

- Amazon Redshift
- Amazon Relational Database Service
- Publicly accessible databases

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-add-connection.html)

Hope this helps !